# Capistrano and XSendFile configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, capistrano, passenger, x-sendfile

I am trying to configure Rails production server with Apache 2.2, Passenger 4.0.59 and XSendFile 0.12. Application is deployed via Capistrano.

Deployed application produces (maybe large) PDF to `#{Rails.root}/tmp` and serves this file using `send_file`.

The problem is that Capistrano uses symlinks to point to currently deployed version of application. XSendFile on the other hand dereferences symlinks and refuses to serve a file if its real location is outside document root even if it is allowed by `XSendFilePath`. Apache's error.log states:

```
(20023)The given path was above the root path: xsendfile: unable to find file: /resolved/path/to/file.pdf
```

Everything works well when I set `PassengerAppRoot` and `XSendFilePath` to the real location of current version of application, without symlinks on the path. But it's OK until next deploy, which requires apache reconfiguration. Not very useful.

How should I configure Capistrano deploy and XSendFile parameters to make it work together?

I tried solutions with `ln -nFs` described in [Capistrano & X-Sendfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115011/capistrano-x-sendfile) and in [mod_xsendfile with symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573853/mod-xsendfile-with-symbolic-links) but none works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work. A few tips for the ones who will have problems with XSendFile

1. I set `XSendFilePath` to user's `$HOME`, there are no symlinks on the path to `$HOME`, so it works. I can accept this from functional and security point of view, but it is obviously a workaround.
2. Be aware that `XSendFilePath` is sensitive to paths containing multiple slashes `/like//this`. I am using apache macros and while concatenating`XSendFilePath` parameter from a few macro parameters I put some obsolete slashes. This caused XSendFile to refuse to send files.

Good luck!